# "/usr/bin/javac: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, java-8

I installed jdk1.8.0_161 in linux server RHEL 7.. I am not able to check java version due to "/usr/bin/javac: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory"

below are the steps i followed to install jdk,

```
cd /opt/jdk1.8.0_161/
alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/java 2
alternatives --config java

There is 1 program that provides 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /opt/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/java

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 1

alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /opt/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/jar 2
alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/javac 2
alternatives --set jar /opt/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/jar
alternatives --set javac /opt/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/javac

java -version
-bash: /usr/bin/java: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory


export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_161
export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_161/jre
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_161/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_161/jre/bin
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you unpacked a tar.gz file in /opt/. This version is obviously trying to use the 32bits `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` . (The 64bits linker is `/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> ld-2.17.so`)

For EL7 please use the "rpm" 8u**162** 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html →
 **jdk-8u162-linux-x64.rpm** :

`# cd Downloads/ && yum install ./jdk-8u162-linux-x64.rpm`

```
# alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_162/bin/java 2
# alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_162/bin/javac 2

# alternatives --config java
# alternatives --config javac
```

No issues ...

Comment: What do you do to fix @Koushic 's issue if you are using a shared resource and therefore don't have root privileges?

Comment: The jdk-8u162-linux-x64.rpm installs to /usr/java/ : root. ..... And /etc/alternatives/ : root. ..... Also : `#` is the root prompt. ....